# Get the latest non-NA value based on date column by group

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping

I have a dataframe having `country_name`, `date` and several columns: `column_1`, `column_2`and `column_3`. I am trying to extract the latest record based on date across several columns.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
| country_name | date        | column_1| column_2| column_3|
| US           | 2016-11-02  | 7.5     | NA      | NA      |
| US           | 2017-09-12  | NA      | NA      | 9       |
| US           | 2017-09-19  | NA      | 8       | 10      |
| US           | 2020-02-10  | 10      | NA      | NA      |
| US           | 2021-03-10  | NA      | NA      | 7.3     |
| US           | 2021-05-02  | NA      | 3       | NA      |
| UK           | 2016-11-02  | NA      | 2       | NA      |
| UK           | 2017-09-12  | 0.5     | 3       | NA      |
 .
 .
```

For the US the desired output is:

```
| country_name | column_1| column_2| column_3|
| US           | 10      | 3       | 7.3     |
```

For `column_1`, the value with the latest date is 10 (date: 2020-02-10),
for `column_2` is 3 (date: 2021-05-02), and for `column_3` is 7.3 (date: 2021-03-10). My goal is to apply this logic across several countries. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>% 
  group_by(country_name) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  select(-date) %>% 
  fill(everything()) %>% 
  slice(n())

#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#> # Groups:   country_name [2]
#>   country_name column_1 column_2 column_3
#>   <chr>           <dbl>    <int>    <dbl>
#> 1 UK                0.5        3     NA  
#> 2 US               10          3      7.3
```

#### Data:

```
read.table(text = "country_name  date         column_1 column_2 column_3
                   US            2016-11-02   7.5      NA       NA      
                   US            2017-09-12   NA       NA       9       
                   US            2017-09-19   NA       8        10      
                   US            2020-02-10   10       NA       NA      
                   US            2021-03-10   NA       NA       7.3     
                   US            2021-05-02   NA       3        NA      
                   UK            2016-11-02   NA       2        NA      
                   UK            2017-09-12   0.5      3        NA", 
           header = T, stringsAsFactors = F) -> df1
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Thanks to @Darren Tsai handling the warning:

```
Warning: Problem while computing `..1 = across(-country_name, ~parse_number(.)).
i 1 parsing failure. row col expected actual 1 -- a number NA NA
```

Adding this line of code:

```
 mutate(across(-country_name, ~str_trim(str_replace_all(., 'NA', ''))))
```

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>% 
  group_by(country_name) %>%
  arrange(date, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  summarise(across(starts_with("column"), ~paste(rev(.), collapse = ' '))) %>% 
  mutate(across(-country_name, ~str_trim(str_replace_all(., 'NA', '')))) %>% 
  mutate(across(-country_name, ~parse_number(.)))
```

```
  country_name column_1 column_2 column_3
  <chr>           <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 UK                0.5        3     NA  
2 US               10          3      7.3
```

**First answer:**

Here is how we could do it:

1. If necessary transform `date` column to date class with `ymd()` function from `lubridate`.
2. group by `country_name`
3. Now comes the trick we use `across` for col1 col2... etc. and collapse in reverse with `paste(rev(.)....` to get the last value to first place. This is important for the next step.
4. Use `parse_number()` from `readr` package that will extract the first number!

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(readr)

df %>% 
  mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>% 
  group_by(country_name) %>%
  arrange(date, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  summarise(across(starts_with("column"), ~paste(rev(.), collapse = ' '))) %>% 
  mutate(across(-country_name, parse_number))
```

```
 country_name column_1 column_2 column_3
  <chr>           <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 UK                0.5        3     NA  
2 US               10          3      7.3
```

Comment: Ok I see thanks. I will check it.

Answer (score 1):

You could `na.omit` and `rev`erse each column and take first `el`ement. Then `rbind`. Take care of the right `order` and if it's `as.Date` formatted.

```
by(transform(dat, date=as.Date(date)), dat$country_name, \(x) {
  cbind(x[1, 1, drop=FALSE], 
        lapply(x[order(x$date), 3:5], \(z) {
          z <- el(rev(na.omit(z)))
          ifelse(length(z) == 1, z, NA_real_)
        }))
}) |> c(make.row.names=FALSE) |> do.call(what=rbind)
#   country_name column_1 column_2 column_3
# 1           UK      0.5        3       NA
# 2           US     10.0        3      7.3
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(country_name = c("US", "US", "US", "US", "US", 
"US", "UK", "UK"), date = c("2016-11-02", "2017-09-12", "2017-09-19", 
"2020-02-10", "2021-03-10", "2021-05-02", "2016-11-02", "2017-09-12"
), column_1 = c(7.5, NA, NA, 10, NA, NA, NA, 0.5), column_2 = c(NA, 
NA, 8L, NA, NA, 3L, 2L, 3L), column_3 = c(NA, 9, 10, NA, 7.3, 
NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can summarise each country across multiple columns with `across()`. The latest non-NA value can be subsetted by `.x[date == max(date[!is.na(.x)])]`.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(country_name) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with("column"),
                   ~ if(all(is.na(.x))) NA else .x[date == max(date[!is.na(.x)])])) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 2 × 4
#   country_name column_1 column_2 column_3
#   <chr>           <dbl>    <int>    <dbl>
# 1 UK                0.5        3     NA  
# 2 US               10          3      7.3
```

---

Another idea:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(country_name) %>%
  arrange(desc(date), .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  summarise(across(starts_with("column"), ~ .x[!is.na(.x)][1])) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution. It uses two sapply calls: one for country and one for column.

```
foo <- structure(list(country_name = c("US", "US", "US", "US", "US", 
"US", "UK", "UK"), date = c("2016-11-02", "2017-09-12", "2017-09-19", 
"2020-02-10", "2021-03-10", "2021-05-02", "2016-11-02", "2017-09-12"
), column_1 = c(7.5, NA, NA, 10, NA, NA, NA, 0.5), column_2 = c(NA, 
NA, 8L, NA, NA, 3L, 2L, 3L), column_3 = c(NA, 9, 10, NA, 7.3, 
NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))


split(foo, foo$country_name)|>
  sapply( function(s) {
    s = s[order(s$date),]
    sapply(s[,3:5], function(x) {
       y = na.omit(x)
       ifelse(length(y)> 0, y[length(y)], NA) })}) |>
  t()

#   column_1 column_2 column_3
#UK      0.5        3       NA
#US     10.0        3      7.3
```